Code Failing with Null Pointer exception as the sheet.getrow is geting NULL. Below is the Error I am getting. Please suggest the right solution
Iteration : 10
Parent row--------------------:154
Parent Row Creation:null
Current row:----------10
error processing the load. Error: null
error processing data load and performing rollback
Closing JDBC connection...
error processing the load. Error: null
error processing data load and performing rollback
Closing JDBC connection...
Error occured during extract process.1 Error: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.services.COMMRBCEExtDynamic.$anonfun$doETL$3(COMMRBCEExtDynamic.scala:182) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158) ~[----workspace_spark_3_1--maven-trees--hive-2.3__hadoop-2.7--org.scala-lang--scala-library_2.12--org.scala-lang__scala-library__2.12.10.jar:?]
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.services.COMMRBCEExtDynamic.$anonfun$doETL$2(COMMRBCEExtDynamic.scala:179) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158) ~[----workspace_spark_3_1--maven-trees--hive-2.3__hadoop-2.7--org.scala-lang--scala-library_2.12--org.scala-lang__scala-library__2.12.10.jar:?]
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.services.COMMRBCEExtDynamic.$anonfun$doETL$1(COMMRBCEExtDynamic.scala:177) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158) ~[----workspace_spark_3_1--maven-trees--hive-2.3__hadoop-2.7--org.scala-lang--scala-library_2.12--org.scala-lang__scala-library__2.12.10.jar:?]
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.services.COMMRBCEExtDynamic.doETL(COMMRBCEExtDynamic.scala:172) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.services.ETLService.doETL(ETLService.scala:191) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]
    at com.bcbsm.ie.etl.main.RedshiftToExcelExt$.main(RedshiftToExcelExt.scala:69) ~[addedFile1823515003766928211FAM_Report_1_0_0-2844a.jar:?]

Expected output:
sheetName: Withhold Report by RBCE - Comm
rowNumber: 10
rowCount: 192
lastRow: 24
Add Rows Completed
Iteration : 10
Parent row--------------------:202
Current row:----------10
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------26
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------42
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------58
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------74
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------90
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------106
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------122
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------138
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------154
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------170
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Current row:----------186
Current CELL:----0
ParCELL Type3
Iteration : 11

Below is the code that is failing.
   //val inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(destFile));
      val fs =FileSystem.get(new URI("s3a://"+IEUtil.getProperty("awsS3BucketName")), new Configuration)
      val inputStream = fs.open(new Path(destFile));
      val workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
      val sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName)
      logger.info("Sheet Name For Comm:" + sheet)
      var lastStoredRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum().toInt;
      logger.info("--------last row:" + lastStoredRowNum)
      var getTheCell = ((dosRowNumber.toInt) * (no_of_Rbce - 1) + 10)
      logger.info("Get the Last Cell:" + getTheCell)
      
      var noforbce = no_of_Rbce - 1.toInt
      logger.info("No of RBCE:" + noforbce)
        for (i <- 10 to 23 by 1) {
        logger.info("Iteration : " + i)
        logger.info("Parent row--------------------:" + ((16 * (no_of_Rbce - 1)) + i).toString())
        val parentRow = sheet.getRow((16.toInt * (no_of_Rbce - 1)).toInt + i.toInt)           
        logger.info("Parent Row Creation:" + parentRow)
        for (j <- 10 to 23 by 1) {
          if (i == j) {
            for (k <- 0 to no_of_Rbce - 2 by 1) {
              var currRow = sheet.createRow(j + (16 * k))
              logger.info("Current row:----------" + (j + (16 * k)))
              val col_count = parentRow.getLastCellNum()
              logger.info("Column Count Cell:" + col_count)

              for (l <- 0 to (col_count - 1) by 1) {
                val parent_cell = parentRow.getCell(l)
                currRow.createCell(l)
                val curr_cell = currRow.getCell(l)
                logger.info("Current CELL:----" + l)

                breakable {
                  if (parent_cell == null) {
                    break
                  } else {
                    val parent_style = parent_cell.getCellStyle()
                    curr_cell.setCellStyle(parent_style)
                    logger.info("ParCELL Type" + parent_cell.getCellType())

                    if (parent_cell.getCellType() == 0.toInt) {
                      curr_cell.setCellValue(parent_cell.getNumericCellValue())
                      logger.info("Numeric  value:" + parent_cell.getNumericCellValue())

                    } else if (parent_cell.getCellType() == 1.toInt) {

                      curr_cell.setCellValue(parent_cell.getStringCellValue())
                      logger.info("string value:" + parent_cell.getStringCellValue())

                    } else if (parent_cell.getCellType() == 2.toInt) {
                      var src_formula = parent_cell.getCellFormula()
                      logger.info("Source formula" + src_formula)
                      var number_list = ("""\d+""".r findAllIn src_formula).toList
                      for (m <- 0 to (number_list.length) - 1 by 1) {
                        src_formula = src_formula.replace(number_list(m).toString(), ((number_list(m).toInt) - 16 * ((no_of_Rbce - 1) - k)).toString())
                      }

                      curr_cell.setCellFormula(src_formula)
                      //logger.info("Formula value:"+ parent_cell.getCellFormula())
                    } else if (parent_cell.getCellType() == 3.toInt) {
                      curr_cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK)
                      //logger.info("Formula value:"+ parent_cell.getCellFormula())
                    } else {
                      logger.info(".")
                    }
                  }
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
        
      for (n <- 0 to (no_of_Rbce - 1) by 1) {
        var headerRow = sheet.getRow(10 + (16 * n));
        var headerCell = headerRow.getCell(0)
        headerCell.setCellValue(rbce_idName(n))
      }

      inputStream.close();

      //val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destFile));
      val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fs.create(new Path(destFile)).toString());
      workbook.write(outputStream);
      workbook.close();
      outputStream.close();

    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logger.info("error processing the load. Error: " + e.getMessage);
        logger.info("error processing data load and performing rollback")
        e.printStackTrace()
        //connection.rollback()
        throw e;
    } finally {

      cleanup();
      stmt.close();
      rs.shutdown();
      //(s"hadoop fs -rm -R  $s3Path_write").!
    }

  }

  def cleanup() {

    /*if (hdfs != null) {
      hdfs.shutdown();
    }*/
  }
}


Well, did you try to debug your code? Which line raise the Nullpointerexception?

Also, consider using more Scala idiomatic code without mutability and/or non nullable values/types.

Would it help you to find the error sooner if you removed the e from the line throw e;?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
